# Reset tab on click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost implemented with three tabs and are functioning. What I wanted to know if there is any way back when to click the same tab is selected, it returns to its initial state (like a reset)?

I managed to do this using the method "setOnClickListener" of each tab and start to get a new activity, but it does not matter because I notice the passage of activity.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what is your issue and what you are expecting from us. Please post code and explain briefly what your issue is.

Comment: I click on the tab and its contents be rebooted without creating new activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one ugly easy way and one more complex way.

```
    // Re-clickable (active) tabs
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0) {
                // Try this :
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); // Ugly easy way
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

                // Or do this :
                SomeActivityGroup.group.onResume(); // More complex way
            } else {
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            }
         }
     }
```

I have little time now, if you like I can post the ActivityGroup code as well later.

** Here it is then:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class SomeActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {

    View rootView;

    // Keep this in a static variable to make it accessible for all the nested
    // activities, lets them manipulate the view
    public static SomeActivityGroup group;

    // Need to keep track of the history if you want the back-button to work
    // properly, don't use this if your activities requires a lot of memory.
    private ArrayList<View> history;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
        group = this;

        // Start the root activity within the group and get its view
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("SomeActivity", new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

        // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup
        replaceView(view);
    }

    public void replaceView(View v) {
        // Adds the old one to history
        if (history.size() == 0) {
            if (rootView != null) {
                history.add(rootView);
                rootView = null;
            }
        }
        history.add(v);
        // Changes this Groups View to the new View.
        setContentView(v);
    }

    public void back() {
        try {
            if (history.size() > 0) {
                history.remove(history.size() - 1);
                setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            SomeActivityGroup.group.back();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        return;
    }

}
```

Just keep in mind that ActivityGroups are deprecated in ICS.

Comment: Ok, I have added the code for the ActivityGroup. If you want to develop for ICS, I recommend using fragments and Action Bar Tabs.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop a new application then I strongly recommend you to use Fragments and some compatibility library, preferably [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com), because the "old" approach with TabHost and TabActivities is deprecated now.

Download the library and take a look at class:

ABSLibraryXX\samples\demos\src\com\actionbarsherlock\sample\demos\app\FragmentTabs.java

I guarantee you will be surprised how powerful and simple it is. When you are switching between Fragments instead of Activities, then the Fragments state persist - they behave like views rather than activities.